# Passing the Parameter value to Web API endpoint with special characters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

Just came across this issue while calling a Web API 2 endpoint for displaying the details of the book based on genre. When genre is "Computing, Internet & Digital Media" ASP.Net Web API 2 framework is not able to bind the value to the route parameter. We have encoded the string i.e. "Computing, Internet & Digital Media" even then it is not bind the value. Please refer the screen short below.

[image]

How can we make framework to bind genre with the value ""Computing, Internet & Digital Media"

Comment: Even after encoding you are converting that to string, which treats character '&' as '&' not as '038'
While Passing you need to pass as 038.

Comment: you mean parameter i.e. genre will have Computing, Internet & Digital Media right that is what we want , but here flow does not reach to method itself.  It is failing during the binding process itself

Comment: However, adding the setting in the web.config as suggested below is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your  URL contains a '&' which is not encoded while passing.
it treats '&' as URL parameter specifier.
Either you can convert this to ASCII code or specify these special characters in config file as bellow :

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
<pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Actually, we are encoding all the special character. if you see the screen shot above while sending the request we are passing the encoded genre.